# ListView not appearing in application

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

im trying to populate my listview beneath my tab function but for some reason its not appearing in my app. I Sampled the code in a external project and it worked so Im not sure why it is not appearing. Have I implemented the activity wrong in the manifest or do I have contrary codes. No errors or logcat issues when the button is selected. Its just a blank page beneath the tab. The page loads but with no list. Thanks

```
XML File
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  Single List Item Design -->
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:textSize="16dip"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>
```

ListmoreActivity

```
package workout.fitty;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;


public class ListmoreActivity extends ListActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // storing string resources into Array
    String[] adobe_products = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.adobe_products);

    // Binding resources Array to ListAdapter
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main, R.id.label, adobe_products));

}
}
```

The Activity in the manifest is added like;

```
<activity android:name=".ListmoreActivity" />
```

Just in case its wrong

Comment: missing setContentView in activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong from the inception of the code refer the link below to learn listview in android...

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Hey. I read that post and I thought I understood it but now I get a "False" return on the page. What would be the reason for this? Any help is greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: may be possible that u r using other version of android mentioned in tutorial.Try to debug the code ur self...

Comment: Please summarise the contents of the linked to page here. At the moment I can't tell whether this answers the question or not, and if the link moves this answer becomes worse than useless.

Comment: I'm not converting this one (yet) because it is the accepted answer, however if this link breaks, the answer becomes useless to future visitors.